# Javascript - How to count character for each line of a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, count

I am designing my website and am struggling with typography. I would like to realize how many characters there are in each line of my paragraph div. Is there any way to do this with Javascript or jQuery?

For example: I have a 720px wide div with an 18px font size, how can I count how many characters there are for each line? If this is feasible I would also like to understand how to count the spaces or exclude them from the count.

I am currently using `$("#mydiv p").text().length` but it counts all characters and not characters for each line.

I appreciate any help and thank you for any replies.

```js
document.write( $("#mydiv p").text().length );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv" style="font-size: 18px; width: 720px; border: 1px solid red;">
<p>This is my div! This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!This is my div!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify what problem you're trying to solve. Counting characters is pointless unless you're using a monospace font.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I would like to follow a typographical rule according to which the optimal length of a paragraph should be such as to contain 45 - 75 characters per line. For this I was looking for a js solution that allows me to count how many characters there are in each line and figure out what width to set my div.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. If you're using a monospace font (where each char is the same width), then it would just be some simple maths (div width / char width), but with variable width font the only way I could think of, is programmatically adding line breaks at certain intervals, but that's not really what your trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I use pt serif font, I don't know if it makes a difference.

Comment: There's the `em` unit, that's the width of the `M` character. Try a width like `40em`: https://jsfiddle.net/ap8bn0su/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to set a character per line limit just use the `ch` unit like so:

```css
.max720{
  width:720px;
  font-size:18px;
}

.max50ch p{
max-width:50ch;
}
```

```html
<div class="max720 max50ch">
  <p><strong>Max 50 characters per line.</strong> One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections.</p>

<p>The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me? " he thought. It wasn't a dream.</p>
  </div>
```

#### Example 2: count characters per line

If you need to get the exact characters per line count, you'll need to to split your text content to an array of characters and and check the line's `offsetHeight`.

```js
let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");
paragraphs.forEach(function (paragraph, p) {
  let text = paragraph.textContent;
  //split to character array
  let textArr = text.split("");
  //append temporary span element
  let line = document.createElement("span");
  paragraph.insertBefore(line, paragraph.firstChild);
  let charCount = 0;
  let charArr = [];
  let lineNo = 1;
  let lineY = line.offsetHeight;

  textArr.forEach(function (char, i) {
   //add text character by character
    line.textContent += char;
    charCount++;
    let currentY = line.offsetHeight;
    //currentY > lineY = new line
    if (currentY > lineY || i == textArr.length - 1) {
      let charPerLine = charCount - 1;
      console.log(`paragraph ${p+1};  line ${lineNo}: ${charPerLine} characters`);
      lineY = currentY;
      charCount = 0;
      lineNo++;
    }
  });
  //remove span
  line.remove();
});
```

```css
.max720{
  width:720px;
  font-size:18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="max720 max72ch">
  <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections.</p>

<p>The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me? " he thought. It wasn't a dream.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works fine. I am grateful for that. A doubt, instead of counting all the paragraphs `p` I want to count only the paragraph that has a certain ID, how do I do it?

Comment: Just change the initial selector to something like this `let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("#customParagraph")`. But quite likely you should rather use a class to avoid duplicate id references (and to style these paragraphs using a #id selector - specificity nuke!)